# With spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update hibernate wrongly finds SYS.CATALOG

Tags: spring, oracle, hibernate, jpa

We're using **Sping** **Boot** and **Hibernate** with **Oracle** in our app and in dev mode at start we set:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

We have a JPA entity call **Catalog** and from it, Hibernate is supposed to create a DB table named **CATALOG** (if it doesn't exist). Apparently, there is a bug in **Hibernate** and instead of not-finding and creating a new **CATALOG** table, it reports:

```
o.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata   : HHH000261: Table found: SYS.CATALOG
```

This happens only with that entity/table and seems that the name **CATALOG** is confusing **Hibernate**. If we change the name it works fine, but we don't want to change the name of the table. We want it to be **CATALOG**.

Does anybody know how we can workaround that problem?

Comment: Contact Hibernate support and ask them to fix it. Maybe you should also read something about public synonyms and Oracle concepts in general. There are other table names which can really be confusing: COMMIT, MODEL, JOIN, .... The CATALOG is the table where Oracle displays some if it's metadata - like the list of tables . If you create a table having the same name, the Oracle's CATALOG table will be shadowed. And possibly Hibernate will be not able to check if the CATALOG table was already created.

Comment: Another work around until you have a permanent fix would be also to use the hbm2ddl to generate the update script to a file. You can invoke the hbm2ddl task in a way so that it outputs the sql script to a file.

Then you can fix the file and executed the SQL update afterwards.

Comment: Thanks guys - not helpful. of course I can fix the script manually, but it should be completely automated - the Ops team is supposed to do that.

Comment: Actually, I've found something. The property hibernate.default_schema=... works ... somewhat ... It works only if I pass it as a command line param. If I put it in the application.properties file, it doesn't affect the script generation ...